# How to create a method that all view controllers have access to?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

By the time my app is complete, I'll have 50 or so view controllers. In order to use my app the user must have a working internet connection.

I have a code that checks if there is a valid connection, however I would have to add the  same code to every `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` for each ViewController (very inefficient in my eyes as I have a Swift file for every VC)

Is there a way to create a "universal" method where I only have the Internet connection code present in one place (and all ViewControllers are able to access it)?

I'm using Swift.

Comment: Inherit UIViewController (RootViewController) - put your code in viewDidLoad - and all others controllers inherit from your RootViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this several ways. You could create a global subclass that you then subclass.

So you have your `MyViewController` class with the code in and then you create subclasses of this instead of `UIViewController`.

Or you could create a category. Or a singleton. Or just a normal class with a class method. etc. that contains the code that you want to run.

Then in your view controllers you can have the code...

```
[SomeSharedClass runThisMethod];
```

In Swift...

```
SomeSharedClass.runThisMethod()
```

As David pointed out. It would be preferred to create a category or extension etc... as subclassing may lead you to having to create subclasses for several different root classes `UITableViewController`, `UIPageViewController`, `UICollectionViewController`, etc...

Comment: by three seconds :)  A more complete answer too. +1

Comment: Note that using a category/extension on `UIViewController` has significant advantages over subclassing it.  Primarily, if you take the subclass approach you may need to subclass `UIViewController`, `UITableViewController`, `UIPageViewController`, etc.  A single category/extension would be usable by all `UIViewController` descendants.

Answer (score 4):

With this use-case, I should sub-class all ViewControllers to a super class (CommonViewController):

```
class CommonViewController : UIViewController {
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad() 
           // do your common works for all sub-classes
       }
}

class MyViewController : CommonViewController {
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()  //call CommonViewController ViewDidLoad
            //... then your work
       }
}
```

Comment: `super.viewDidLoad` calls the superclass, not the parent.

Comment: As I point out in Fogmeisters's answer, the subclass approach is suboptimal for most applications since you typically have descendants of both `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController` at a minimum, so have to have the same code multiple places.  Better to create an extension.

Comment: YES and NO.  You cannot add additional attribute to category. Category is for additional methods.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the opportunity to do an extension now in Swift 2 to help me send alert msgs instead of writing the code down everytime in every view controller i just write down the text string. I used UIAlertController for the newer IOS versions and UIAlertView for the old ones.

Just make a new .swift file and write down the extension you need for the class you want.

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController{

func userNamePassAlert(theTitle: String , theMessage: String){

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let userTextFieldEmptyAlert = UIAlertController(title: theTitle, message: theMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let userTextFieldEmptyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        })
        userTextFieldEmptyAlert.addAction(userTextFieldEmptyAction)
        self.presentViewController(userTextFieldEmptyAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        let userTextFieldEmptyAlert = UIAlertView()
        userTextFieldEmptyAlert.title = theTitle
        userTextFieldEmptyAlert.message = theMessage
        userTextFieldEmptyAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")

        userTextFieldEmptyAlert.show()

    }
}

}
```

And this is how i call it in my view controllers

```
else {
         userNamePassAlert("Error Loging In", theMessage: "Username or Password field is empty. Try again")

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this, if you're really set on it, is to subclass UIViewController and put it in the init method.  That way it'll run first each time a VC is instantiated.  So, instead of extending UIViewController for all of your VCs, you'll extend YOUR new VC class.